# Wordpress PHP - WP Query - Order by Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to order by a custom field in my posts, I have the following code, its not giving any errors, but its like the order by and meta parameters in the wp query do not exist.

```
if ($myURL[3] == 'recorded_lesson')
            {
                foreach (get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'rl_categories') as $cat) {
                        $catID = $cat->term_id;
                }
                $myTaxQuery = array(
                    'post_type' => 'recorded_lessons',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'rl_categories',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $catID
                         )
                      ),
                    'meta_key' => 'rl_number',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                    );
                $query['tax_query'] = $myTaxQuery;
            }
            return $query;
        }, 10, 2 );
```

What am I doing wrong here please ?

Comment: Are you using ACF plugin for the custom fields?

Comment: No I am not, custom fields are in the post itself as custom meta keys

Answer (score 0):

Change code like this and try

```
if ($myURL[3] == 'recorded_lesson')
{
    foreach (get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'rl_categories') as $cat) {
            $catID = $cat->term_id;
    
    $args=array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,    
        'post_type' => 'recorded_lessons',
        'meta_key' => 'rl_number',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'rl_categories', //double check your taxonomy name in you dd 
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $catID,
            ),
           ),
         );
    }
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
}
return $wp_query;
}, 10, 2 );
```